# Error on compile qml-material on windows

Tags: c++, qt, cmake, mingw, qml

How to compile and install the [qml-material](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) on windows7 machine ?

First of all I clone and compile extra-cmake-modules like below:

```
git clone git://anongit.kde.org/extra-cmake-modules
cd extra-cmake-modules
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

After that I run the `Make` command but with no output!(No error and no change!)

And for compile the **qml-material** I use the below instruction:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..
```

But I get **error**:

```
 -- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
 -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
 -- Check for working C compiler: C:/bin/cxx/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe
 -- Check for working C compiler: C:/bin/cxx/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/gcc.exe -- works
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
 -- Detecting C compile features
 -- Detecting C compile features - done
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/bin/cxx/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/g++.exe
 -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/bin/cxx/Qt/Qt5.5.1/Tools/mingw492_32/bin/g++.exe -- works
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
 -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
 -- Detecting CXX compile features
 -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
CMake Error at C:/Users/me/Documents/Github/ecm/ECMConfig.cmake:35 (include):  
 include could not find load file:

    C:/Users/me/share/ECM/modules//ECMUseFindModules.cmake
Call Stack (most recent call first):
       CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:16 (include):
 include could not find load file:

    KDEInstallDirs

CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:17 (include):
 include could not find load file:

    KDECMakeSettings

 CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:18 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    KDECompilerSettings

 CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:1 (include):
  include could not find load file:

    ECMMarkAsTest

 CMake Error at tests/CMakeLists.txt:13 (ecm_mark_as_test):
  Unknown CMake command "ecm_mark_as_test".


 -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I was try to use QtCreator to compile ECM and also the after that the qml-material, ECM compile and build fine without any error but the qml-material show above error too!!!

thanks,

Comment: Well, you do not really need to "build" qml-material. Simply copy the plain QML dir structure from https://github.com/papyros/qml-material/tree/develop/modules to "Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw/qml/Material" and from https://github.com/papyros/qml-material/tree/develop/modules/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Material to "Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Material"

Comment: @sk2212: Thank you for your comment you literally saved me hours of trouble!

Comment: @nwestbury You are welcome! Maybe I should provide the comment as an answer ;-)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will provide my comment as an answer for a better overview:

To use [qml-material](https://github.com/papyros/qml-material) it is not really necessary to "build" the project with cmake because the project itself contains only plain qml files.
I do not know why the guys switched from qmake to cmake system.

However all you need to do is to simply copy the file structure to your local file system:

- checkout the project with `git clone https://github.com/papyros/qml-material.git`
- copy the content of `qml-material/modules/Material` to `Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw/qml/Material` and `qml-material/modules/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Material` to `Qt5.5.1/5.5/mingw/qml/QtQuick/Controls/Styles/Material` where `mingw` stands for your Qt platform. Could also be `gcc4.9` or something like this.

That`s all.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this is work on windows build but not on android!

Comment: That should also work for Android platform! You have to replace `mingw` with `android_armv7`. What error message do you get?

Comment: Ah thanks for your comment I forget to copy to other kits too, after that the android version build and run success but some of it's icon lost! [Screenshot](http://g37i.imgup.net/qml_materieb01.jpg). At the end of compile output in QtCreator show this [warrning](http://pastebin.com/raw/jPefbtRr)

Comment: Did you add the `svg` package within your pro file?

Comment: Thanks for that note!, I add the svg to pro file this is [my pro file](http://pastebin.com/raw/5S4hmN70) and after that change when I get android build that [warning](http://pastebin.com/raw/6dPqdJvZ) still appear just like past but when I install and run android application some of it's icons shown but others not please check this [picture](http://t40i.imgup.net/qml_materi43e5.jpg) I draw red rectangle, on desktop version no problem but on android not icon on that section!

Comment: I had also this issue. I fixed it by simply create near the `.svg` icon file a corresponding `.png` file. I adjusted the `Icon.qml` component of the qml-material that it will load `png` icons for Android platform and `svg` for all other platforms.

Comment: Thank you for all your help